# jQuery: Pass plugin a string reference to be used as object in plugin

Tags: jquery

This may be a little non-standard.....

```
// JavaScript Document
(function( $ ){
$.fn.editAsPage = function(options) {       
    var settings =  {};     
    if(options){ jQuery.extend(settings, options); }        
    return this.each( function(){           
        var el = jQuery(this);
        alert(settings.source.attr("class"));                         
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

My question lies around the settings.source parameter. attr("class") is just an example, there are several attributes I need to get from a particular DOM element, but the user of the plugin may need to define which DOM element settings.source is.

So you say, just pass in an jQuery object.  Where I run into a problem is that I, for one, want to reference the parent of "this" in the plugin.

For example:

```
jQuery(".edit").editAsPage({
        'source':jQuery(this)                                                              
    });
```

Here, jQuery(this) won't refer to element with the .edit class since it will interpret it before calling the editAsPage function.

I guess the question is, can I pass a string to the editAsPage function to be interpreted as a jQuery object in the plugin?

This is a very simple example.  The reason, I don't just use "this" inside the plugin, is because "source" could change.  It may very well be something like:

'source':jQuery(this).parents("selector:first")

Not sure if that made any sense what I'm asking.  It makes sense in my mind. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using callbacks for this. First step is to change your thinking of how this should work by making `source` a callback. Next you need to modify `source` to pass a new `this` definition using JS's `call()` mtheod (or `apply()` when applicable).

Your plugin code modified would look like:

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.editAsPage = function(options) {       
    var settings =  {};     
    if(options){ jQuery.extend(settings, options); }        
    return this.each( function(){           
        var el = jQuery(this);
        settings.source.call(this, el);                       
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Your user then would use it like this:

```
$('.edit').editAsPage({ 
  source:function(){
    $('.parent').append('<strong>#'+$(this).parent().attr('id')+'</strong>');
    $('.id').append('<strong>#'+$(this).attr('id')+'</strong>');
  }
});
```

See a live example here: http://jsbin.com/ipafe4

Play with the live example here: http://jsbin.com/ipafe4/edit

What we did was change what "`this`" meant then gave it back to the `source` function / callback the user is defining.

Info on call and apply: http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/apply_call.htm